# Distributing work across workers in Rust

Tags: rust

```
use std::iter;

fn worker_sum(from: u64, to: u64) -> u64 {
    range(from, to).fold(0u64, |sum, x| sum + x)
}

fn main() {
    let max = 5u64;
    let step = 2u64;

    let (sender, receiver) = channel::<u64>();
    for x in iter::range_step_inclusive(0u64, max, step) {
        let end = if x + step > max { max } else { x + step };
        //println!("{} -> {} = {}", x, end, worker_sum(x, end));
        let local_sender = sender.clone();
        spawn(proc(){
            local_sender.send(worker_sum(x, end));
        });
    }
    loop {
        match receiver.try_recv() {
            Ok(x) => println!("{}", x),
            Err(_) => break,
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error:

> task '' failed at 'sending on a closed channel', /home/rustbuild/src/rust-buildbot/slave/nightly-linux/build/src/libsync/comm/mod.rs:573

I somehow understand the problem, but how to properly "select" from the channel? The documentation is really sparse, even though I'm using the nightly build, which is said to have improved the docs (since version 0.13).

So my questions are:

1. How to solve the problem with as little structural changes in the code as possible?
2. How to make the code idiomatic?

Answer (score 3):

The problem you have here is that the channel becomes closed by the reading task before all data is sent. Your loop is:

```
loop {
    match receiver.try_recv() {
        Ok(x) => println!("{}", x),
        Err(_) => break,
    }
}
```

In this loop, your receiver breaks as soon as it meets and error. Once the loop is broken, your function will reach the end of its scope and the receiver will be destroyed. Once this is done, any attempt to send more data will fail.

The problem here, is that your receiver gets an `Err(Empty)` because **the senders have not yet sent anything**. You must wait for them and only break when meeting an `Err(Disconnected)`

You need to change your code to something like this (explanations in comments) :

```
use std::iter;

fn worker_sum(from: u64, to: u64) -> u64 {
    range(from, to).fold(0u64, |sum, x| sum + x)
}

fn main() {
    let max = 5u64;
    let step = 2u64;

    let (sender, receiver) = channel::<u64>();

    for x in iter::range_step_inclusive(0u64, max, step) {
        let end = if x + step > max { max } else { x + step };
        // here, each thread will own its own sender, and the channel will
        // be closed once all senders are destroyed.
        let local_sender = sender.clone();
        spawn(proc(){
            local_sender.send(worker_sum(x, end));
            // Once we reach here, the sender of this task is destroyed.
        });
    }

    // We destroy the sender of the main task,
    // because we don't want to wait for it:
    // it would deadlock the program
    drop(sender);

    loop {
        match receiver.try_recv() {
            Ok(x) => println!("{}", x),
            // We break only if the channel is closed,
            // it means that all senders are finished.
            Err(e) if e == ::std::comm::Disconnected => { break; },
            _ => {}
        }
    }
}
```